# issue with date and time comparision in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

i am trying to unreserve a book as the reservation time is 24 hours after its expiry in library automation system but it is not working . following is the code which is not working

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();

            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from book_reserve_tbl;", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                string todate_str;
                DateTime reserve_todate, current_datetime;
                current_datetime = DateTime.Now;
                string book_id;
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    todate_str = dr.GetValue(4).ToString(); ;//this will assign the reserveToDate col value
                    String is_reserve = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    reserve_todate = Convert.ToDateTime(todate_str);
                    if (reserve_todate < current_datetime && is_reserve == "YES" )
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>condition true</script>");
                        book_id = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        UpdateCurrentStock(book_id);
                        UpdateBookReservation(book_id);
                    }

                    
                }
                con.Close();
                
            }
        }
       
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
```

plz help as i have no experience of it

Regards

Comment: Soooo... What's the actual problem? also, its always best to store datetime as an actual date time construct in a database, not as a *string* (if your db has such facilities)

Comment: You might want to specify in what way it is not working, preferably with some examples of input data and observed behaviour vs expected behaviour - it would make helping much easier

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind so far is time zone.. make sure that you're comparing times within the same time zone and if not, then you need to make your `current_datetime` variable match the timezone of the database field by doing `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(x)` where `x` is the offset for the necessary time zone (better yet, store the DB date field as UTC and just use `DateTime.UtcNow`). But as the others have said, the question needs more detail before we can offer anything other than a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate time between two DateTime values, you should use TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan elapsed;
DateTime time1;
DateTime time2;

elapsed = time1.Subtract(time2);
//or with DateTime.Now
elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time1);
```

Never use string to store DateTime values!

Comment: thank u all for repl.user reserve book for 24 hrs only and after 24 hrs its reservation should be expired/canceled. now in sql srver i have a field with DateTime data type, not just string. now when i compare the DateTime in my given code it doesn't work. there may be one reason that current_datetime variable format is   24/09/2020 12:52:40 PM and what store in Database is 2020-09-24 12:52:40.000 now if the format is not the same there may be issue but  how can i save my date time in sql server database with the following format       24/09/2020 12:52:40. plz help

Comment: Pretty sure `if (reserve_todate < current_datetime && is_reserve == "YES" )` is correct. both `<` and `==` [have a higher operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators#operator-precedence) than `&&` so the parentheses are unnecessary

Comment: @brads3290: thanks, you are right! sorry for the wrong information! I corrected my answer

Comment: @brads. yes i didnt use any paranthesis.

Comment: @ brads3290. i have displayed both the current date and time and the one saved in database . their format is excalty the same . then why the condition doesn't tickled/true. i have chnaged the system date by 3 days and then the condition must true but it didin;t